# Комп. медленно работает

Tags: windows

Компьютер очень медленно грузится, работает. Все протестировал все нормально, процессор менял но все равно медленно, что может быть?

Comment: что значит медленно грузится?скорее всего у тебя или много прог стоит в автозагрузке,либо запущено много служб,вначале посмотри автозагрузку,потом отключи ненужные службы,это если я правильно понял.а вообще,как-то вопрос поставлен не корректно - медленно грузится: медленнее чем что? какая винда? какие программы установлены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставь линукс и тебе не понадобится думать над всем что описали выше.

Answer (score 0):

Да полностью согласен с tukan зайдите в автозагрузку (**msconfig** через командную строку в любой винде) и поотключайте все ненужное(там разные качалки,винампы,адоб апдейты и прочее), службы трогать только если у Вас есть опыт и Вы понимаете зачем эта служба и для чего ее нужно отключить. Если это не поможет тогда нужно больше сведений про систему и про используемое железо чтоб сделать какой-то вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Был Админом(где то год 2000-2003).
Дефрагментация - то с чего наш секретарь начинает борьбу за производительность ПК.
Она её делала примерно 2-3 в год (сама она её запускать не умела, а учить, от греха подальше, не хотелось). Её результат устраевал.

Answer (score 0):

Какие параметры компа? Запустите диспетчер задач, и посмотрите, может там ЦП или ОЗУ перегружен. Тормозят систему также программы, которые чересчур активно читают хард-диск. Правильный был коммент за автозагрузку. Иная причина -- если у Вас стоит не один антивирус, и они дерутся между собой. Или же сам антивирус тормозит систему. Сколько у Вас программ в автозапуске, какая ОС, параметры компа и какие тяжеловесные программы у Вас установлены?

Answer (score 0):

1. Оперативки мало может быть
2. Вирусы
3. Ошибки исправь
4. Windows7 максимальную ставь и комп не будет тормозить
5. Есть такие вирусы которые проц и оперативку жрут под 100%!!! Отпишись!

Answer (score 0):

Операционная система скорее всего виндавс :). 
 1. Самый простой путь 100% - переустановить систему.
 2. Установить антивирус, убрать почти всё из автозагрузки (msconfig), отключить службы(вот это кстати с осторожность делать), удалить ненужные программы, поставить какой нить оптимизатор системы.
 3. Поставить Ubuntu ;), скоро, кстати, релиз новой версии. (вариант не для домохозяек)